# Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)

Tags: node.js, node-sass

Currently using `"node-sass": "4.14.1"` version in package.json. Below is the error I am getting while building.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass- 
loader/..../toastr.scss
Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit 
with Unsupported runtime (88)
```

Below is what I have tried.

Did uninstall and reinstall of `node-sass`, ran `npm rebuild node-sass` also removed `package-lock.json` and ran `npm update` and then `npm cache clean --force`

I have also tried using node-sass version `"^5.00"` still it shows up the same issue. How to resolve this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like sass-loader released an update (10.0.5) to support node-sass v5 https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/pull/899

Comment: The update with 10.0.5 with node-sass v5 matches to solve the above issue. Thanks for your time.